# how to speed up the order by query in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

> my below pagination query runs faster (2.5 sec) without order by .
>   if I use order by it get slower (180 sec).
>   Total number of record is only 90000

```
select * from(
select i.*,rownum rno from (
select opp.updat,nvl(s.name,c.vemail),s.name,c.vemail
from sfa_opportunities opp,sfa_company s, customer c
where opp.companyid = c.companyid(+)
and   opp.custid = c.custid(+)
and   opp.companyid = s.companyid(+)
and   opp.sfacompid = s.sfacompid(+)
order by 2 asc, 1 asc
)i) where rno >= 1 and rno <= 30
```

> I have given the explain plan below for reference.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                        | Name               | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                 |                    | 97980 |   110M|       | 14137   (1)| 00:03:18 |
|*  1 |  VIEW                            |                    | 97980 |   110M|       | 14137   (1)| 00:03:18 |
|   2 |   COUNT                          |                    |       |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    VIEW                          |                    | 97980 |   109M|       | 14137   (1)| 00:03:18 |
|   4 |     SORT ORDER BY                |                    | 97980 |  6602K|    15M| 14137   (1)| 00:03:18 |
|   5 |      NESTED LOOPS OUTER          |                    | 97980 |  6602K|       | 13137   (1)| 00:03:04 |
|*  6 |       HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER      |                    | 97980 |  3635K|  1136K|   614   (1)| 00:00:09 |
|   7 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL         | SFA_COMPANY        | 34851 |   714K|       |    58   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   8 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL         | SFA_OPPORTUNITIES  | 97980 |  1626K|       |   390   (1)| 00:00:06 |
|*  9 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| CUSTOMER           |     1 |    31 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 10 |        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | PK_CUSTOMER_CUSTID |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("RNO"<=30 AND "RNO">=1)
   6 - access("OPP"."COMPANYID"="S"."COMPANYID"(+) AND "OPP"."SFACOMPID"="S"."SFACOMPID"(+))
   9 - filter("OPP"."COMPANYID"="C"."COMPANYID"(+))
  10 - access("OPP"."CUSTID"="C"."CUSTID"(+))
```

Comment: I don't see any obvious index, because 6-7 columns would seem to be involved in the inner query.

Comment: Index is created for both the where clause and order by clause column.but index is not using by this query

Comment: You would need a rather large index to cover all the columns involved in the query.

Answer (score 0):

You're sorting on `nvl(s.name,c.vemail)`, then `opp.updat`. My guess is the NVL may prevent a lot of optimization, because Oracle can't tell what the value of that column is going to be  without looking at every row in the joined result. You could try adding indexes on those three columns or a function based index on `nvl(s.name,c.vemail)`.

Comment: how to create function based index for two column of different table

Comment: Oh I didn't notice those were in two different tables. Yeah, that wouldn't work. You could try creating an index on (companyid, name) and (companyid, vemail).